# PowerShell からNew-MailContactのコマンドレットを使って連絡先を追加したいです

Tags: powershell

PowerShell からOutlookの宛先を登録するバッチを作りたいです。

以下のコマンドレットをPowerShellから実行すると、当然Outlookのインスタンスが取れてないので、
"コマンドレット、関数、スクリプト ファイル、または操作可能なプログラムの名前として認識されません。"
のエラーとなります。
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-mailcontact?view=exchange-ps

質問としては、

1. どうやってこのコマンドレットを使用すれば良いのか、順序だててご教示いただきたいです。
2. PowerShellでMS 製品を操作するときに参考になる、書籍・サイトなどご存知でしたらご教示いただきたいです

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `New-MailContact` はそもそもExchange Serverのコマンドレットであり、Outlookは参照しないのですが。

Answer (score 0):

> どうやってこのコマンドレットを使用すれば良いのか、順序だててご教示いただきたいです。

このコマンドレットの使用方法は私もわからないのですが、
おそらくWEB版のoutlookだと思います。
もしかして投稿主さんは、オフライン版のoutlookで連絡先を登録したいのではないでしょうか
（間違っていたらすみません。）
その場合は以下のコードで可能です。

```
#Set-MailContact

$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

#https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olitemtype
#olContactItem  2
$objContact = $outlook.CreateItem(2)

$objContact.FullName = "powershellTest"


$objContact.Save()
```

> PowerShellでMS 製品を操作するときに参考になる、書籍・サイトなどご存知でしたらご教示いただきたいです

良い書籍がないのが現状です。
ですので、私が勉強した方法をご提示します。

まずVBAでやりたいことを「実装」or「WEBでソースコードを参照」します。
次にそれをpowershellで書き換えます。書き換える際はNew-Object -ComObjectで
ExcelなりOutlookなりのオブジェクトを作ってください。

以上です。